# How to filter 1 column on 'unique', and second column on 'most occuring' in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, unique

I want to filter 2 large columns in Google Spreadsheets.
The outcome from column 1 must only show the unique values
The outcome from column 2 must show the most occuring value for each unique value from 1.

Example dataset:

> - NL  1
> - NL  1
> - NL  2
> - NL  3
> - BE  2
> - BE  2
> - BE  4
> - BE  2
> - USA 6
> - USA 5
> - USA 6
> - USA 6
> - FR  5
> - FR  4
> - FR  2
> - FR  3
> - FR  1
> - FR  2
> - LUX 2

the outcome would be:

> - NL  1
> - BE  2
> - USA 6
> - FR  2
> - LUX 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),QUERY({A:B,A:A},"select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1, Col2 order by count(Col3) desc"),{1,2},0))`

[image]

Sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LwRiKACY4Myp_1NtkFkvtTy1xRvNPx0u5e-Pi0SuzGI/edit?usp=sharing

If your local settings differs from the US then use formula:
`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A;A:A<>""));QUERY({A:B\A:A};"select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1, Col2 order by count(Col3) desc");{1\2};0))`

**The number of times some values occur**

This part of formula is counting all the data, putting the most frequent to the top:

`QUERY({A:B,A:A},"select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1, Col2 order by count(Col3) desc")`

Comment: The formula gives for me a parsing error.
I did replace the "," with ";" within the cell ranges , so A:A;A:A .

Comment: for my dataset the 2 columns are both columns with text and not with numbers.

Comment: Please provide sample with this error. In my case the formula works with text too

Comment: Google mail
Google web
Google web
Google mail
Google web
Facebook (direct)
Facebook web
Facebook web
Facebook web
Affiliate google
Affiliate google
Affiliate google
Affiliate web
Affiliate mail
Instagram (direct)
Instagram np
www.google.com images
www.google.com images
www.google.com images
Adwords cpc
Adwords cpc
Adwords cpc
Adwords web
Adwords web
Adwords cpc
Adwords cpc
Adwords cpc
Adwords mail

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to enter the set correctly in a comment

Comment: I meant, you could make the new file and share it. I'll add a sample file into the answer

Comment: also it gives an error when I replace the "," with ";" within the cell ranges , so A:A;A:A

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBmlkLzEj8rPZdesv5GHc5abZztr087wwE9VYJeI14U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've updated the answer for your local settings. Should work now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBmlkLzEj8rPZdesv5GHc5abZztr087wwE9VYJeI14U/edit#gid=0

Comment: and with what formula do I show the number of times it did occur?

Comment: I mean like a 'countif' formula which shows how many times the most occuring value did occur in a third column?

Comment: so a third column which shows how many time the most occuring value did occur within the shortrange

Comment: You may try in the vlookup state return column 3: `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A;A:A<>""));QUERY({A:B\A:A};"select Col1, Col2, count(Col3) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1, Col2 order by count(Col3) desc");{1\2\3};0))`

Comment: Thank you max!, one final question; is it also possible to have a fourth column showing the total number of rows for each value from the first column?

Comment: That's easier to do with separate query: `"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1"`

Comment: sorry to bother you again, i would like to know if it is also possible to not show only the most occuring value, but also the second, third, and so on? MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP SO FAR

Comment: I suggest you open enother Q for this.